# getting issue of mic open while submitting google assistant

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have submitted an action on google assistant but it was not approved from google assistant team due to this issue "Your Action leaves the mic open for a user command without a prompt".

For this, I have tried some google solution but issue is not resolved yet.
I have ended the conversation by `agent.end();` command and also tried `conv.close();` but both the solution doesn't helped to me.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, this response from the review team is a design problem, not a coding problem.

It means that you have said something, but not prompted the user to reply to you. So the user does not know what to do next.

For example, if we had this conversation:

```
Action: What is your favorite color?
User:   Blue
Action: Great, I'll remember that it is blue.
```

and then nothing happening, the review team would flag it for keeping the microphone open without making it clear what the user should do next.

We can change this to something like:

```
Action: What is your favorite color?
User:   Blue
Action: Great, I'll remember that it is blue. What would you like to do next?
```

and it will pass review.

If you actually want to end your conversation instead of asking the user something else, make sure you close the conversation. If your conversation isn't closing when it should be, then update your question to include the code that doesn't seem to be working.